# C# couple Graphics to UseCase object

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I've got this method:

```
public void createUseCase(int width, int height)
{
    Graphics g = mainPanel.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    g.DrawEllipse(p, width, height, 100, 50);
    g.Dispose();
}
```

This makes a [UseCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) in my panel. I've got a UseCase class aswel. Here I store the UseCase information.

```
UseCase useCase = new UseCase();
useCase.name = 'UseCase 1';
useCase.description = 'UseCase 1';
```

A UseCase can be edited. How do I get the right UseCase object when somebody clicks on the Graphics UseCase in my panel? How do I associate them?

I'm working in winforms.

Comment: OnClick event is a behavior (which has nothing to do with graphics)... any chance you post your **UseCase** class or at least provide some information about the platform you are working on (winforms, wpf, asp.net, etc..)

Comment: _Graphics g = mainPanel.CreateGraphics();_ Wrong. Always use the Paint event's e.Graphics object for persisting graphics!!

Comment: I don't see how you can currently make the connection between an ellipse on a panel and the UseCase object. Maybe you should encapsulate the drawing and data in a container class? So each time you want add a UseCase, you create an instance of the container class which draws itself (remembering where it is) and assigns a UseCase object to the shape. Then when you get a click, see which got clicked, and you have the relevant UseCase.

Comment: @stuartd great solution. Is it not possible to give the graphic some kind of Id?

Comment: No, you can't assign data to graphics, they're just pixels on the form.

Comment: Thanks @stuartd I will accept your answer.